# Call class method instide template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm pretty new about template programming and I could not find any related question, sorry if already exists a similar question.

I have my template class

```
    template<class T>
    class MyTemplate
    {
      public:
       virtual void set(const T& val) { value_ = val; }
       virtual T get() const { return value_; }
       // other stuff


      private:
       T value_;
    }
```

and a custom class

```
class Foo
{
   void bar();
}
```

Then I declare a variable

```
MyTemplate<Foo> var;
```

How can I call the *bar()* method from *var* ?

Comment: How do you represent `T` (resp. `Foo`) in the template class?

Comment: `bar()` is not member of `MyTemplate`, you can't do `var.bar()`

Comment: What “things” do you do in `MyTemplate`? Depending on what you do, the answer could be very different.

Comment: Unclear what you want to know! If MyTemplate derives from T, you can do var.bar(). Read CRTP for that.

Comment: @DanielH It is an interface to add functionality and I don't want to bind it through intheritance

Comment: @Moia What are you adding functionality to? `T`? What functionality are you adding? What functionality are you adding? How do you expect people to use this added functionality?

Comment: @DanielH sorry I don't understand why does it matters? I have my Foo class inside MyTemplate and I'd like to call the method bar() from MyTemplate<Foo> variable, isn't it a matter of syntax?

Comment: @Moia It does matter, but now that you’ve update the question to show the inside of your template it’s answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call bar() you need an instance of Foo somewhere. As already mentioned, you could use inheritance. I see that the question has been edited to add such a member. You can't call members of the template type directly. You could add a wrapper in the MyTemplate, for instance 'doBar()'. You could also (though it's not a good idea) expose the Foo member by making it public.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyTemplate
{
public:
     void doBar() { value_.bar(); }
public:
    T value_;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    void bar();
};

void Foo::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Foo::bar()\n";
}

int main()
{
    MyTemplate<Foo> var;
    var.doBar();
    var.value_.bar();
}
```

BTW any other old timers reminded of [Swaine's Flames](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/swaines-flames-two-pomodoros-at-foo-bar/221600773) in Dr Dobbs journal?

Comment: Thank you. If I would add a method returning the pointer of the inner variable, like T* instance() { return &value } I should be able to do that, but it is a bad practice?

Comment: @Moia At that point it would be much better to ust make `value` a public member of `MyTemplate`, and avoid the virtual `get`ters and `set`ters. Which you should consider doing anyway.

Comment: @Moia In general I would advise against exposing class internals.

Comment: Ok now it's more clear, thank to both. Anyway, I actually don't understand so much downvote considering I said at the beginning of my post that I'm a beginner about template, an obvious question could not be so obvious for a beginner.

Comment: @Moia I agree with Paul that you don’t want to expose class internals, but it looks like in this situation you shouldn’t really consider the value an internal detail.